# Open app on firebase notification received in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-notifications

I want to open the application automatically when a firebase notification is received, without user interaction. means when my application is killed or in the background and when the user receives a firebase notification the application should open automatic without user interaction or clicking on the notification is this possible in the flutter

I want to add this feature in the video calling application that when I receive a notification the call screen with accept reject button should render and I also want to add the autoanswer feature in it.

Comment: You can achieve this in Android but Its not possible in iOS for now,
For android its time sensitive notifications and for iOS most you can do is set an custom ringtone when notification is received,

You can use the below mentioned library for most of your notification needs:-https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in Android but Its not possible in iOS for now, For android its **Full-screen intent notifications** and for iOS most you can do is set an custom ringtone when notification is received, You can use the below mentioned library for most of your notification needs:-[pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

Answer (score -1):

yes, obviously it's possible

u can do like this

demo video link : [click here for watch video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kt-D6I-z3OC5MaWEY2aU7Hio742g8aNc/view?usp=sharing)

```
Future<void> _showNotification() async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your channel id',
      'your channel name',
      channelDescription: 'your channel description',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
      // playSound: false,
    );
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      'plain title',
      'plain body',
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'item x',
    );
  }
```

Comment: but this will only show notification right not open app autometically ? - @Jenis Radadiya

Comment: no, it's will not only show notifications, but they also open the app automatically

Comment: yes it will open application but when user touch on it but i want that when i receive notification at that time application should open without click on notification

Comment: oh, now I understand your question, but  @Sumita Naiya  This does not happen, if you find the solution then plz inform me. thank you.